# IPV4 linux networking configuration

Tags: networking, iptables, linux-networking

I am having problems figuring out what I configured wrong.  I can't get packets back from the velodyne onto a Fedora server with 2 eth interfaces em1 and em2. I have velodyne connected to em1 host to host with eth cable.

I know the velodyne is pumping out UDP packets on 2368 I can see them on wireshark.  I know velodyne is reacting because it responds to ping:

```
ping 192.168.0.27
PING 192.168.0.27 (192.168.0.27) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.0.27: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=1.36 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.27: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.521 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.27: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.353 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.27: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.485 ms
```

It writes out broadcast UDP datagrams on 255.255.255.255. Host address on em1 is 192.168.0.200.  velodyne is 192.168.0.67

```
ifconfig -a
em1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.200  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 192.168.255.255
        inet6 fe80::222:19ff:feab:d328  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:22:19:ab:d3:28  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 20457575  bytes 24210246456 (22.5 GiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 52  bytes 6272 (6.1 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Here is the route table:

```
     route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         131.135.134.240 0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 em2
131.135.134.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 em2
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 em1
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1003   0        0 em2
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 em1
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 em1
```

I started a C UDP socket but it remains unconnected

```
netstat -an | grep udp
udp        0      0 192.168.0.200:2368      0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:43329           0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:43348           0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*  



ss -l | grep 2368
tcp    UNCONN     0      0        192.168.0.200:ipproto-2368               *:*
```

Here is an extracted header from a IP/TCP/UDP packet from the velodyne:

```
Ethernet II, Src: Velodyne_20:13:62 (60:76:88:20:13:62), Dst: Broadcast (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff)
1   0.000000000 192.168.0.27    255.255.255.255 UDP 1248    Source port: opentable(2368) 
 Destination port: opentable (2368)

User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: opentable (2368), Dst Port: opentable (2368)
```

What am I doing wrong?  Does it matter it's an IPV4 and IPV6 interface on at the same time?  Is there another way add host to routing table?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I would check is that you don't have a firewall blocking the incoming UDP datagrams.  If you can see them in Wireshark but they're not getting through to the application, that would be a good indicator that something is blocking them.

Without knowing more about your server it's hard to say exactly what's doing the blocking, but being a Fedora system it's most likely [netfilter](http://www.netfilter.org/), which is part of the Linux kernel.

You can check what firewall rules are in place for inbound connections using `iptables -vL INPUT` (as root), or you can use Fedora's GUI by running `system-config-firewall` as detailed [in the fedora docs](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/11/html/Security_Guide/sect-Security_Guide-Firewalls-Basic_Firewall_Configuration.html).

If you want to add a rule to the table to allow this kind of traffic into your system, I'd use this command:

```
sudo iptables -t filter -A INPUT -i em1 -p udp --dport 2368 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Ok thanks I will try tomorrow.  But how is wireshark avoiding blocking / able to see? Because I have it run it on sudo / root access?

Comment: Wireshark uses [libpcap (or WinPcap)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pcap) which provides an APi for capturing packets before the rest of the OS even sees them.  Security privileges are required for this, for obvious reasons.

Comment: No change.  It has netfilter, nfnet_queue installed as well I tried removing those kmods and flushing the iptables. It still won't allow packets into user space. I disabled selinux and removed rpms  no change.

Comment: Is there a Fedora kernel without netfilter nf_nat installed I can use? It's nonsense having to extract multiple open source projects I don't need.

Comment: None that I'm aware of, but I'm not sure.  Removing kmods seems a bit extreme to get a pretty basic functionality to work.  I certainly don't mean this as a slight to your programming ability, but are you absolutely 100% sure that your program is able to accept incoming packets?  I'd be very curious to find out what happens when you run `sudo nc -lup 2368` to open a listening socket.  I'm pretty much stumped otherwise.

Comment: Also, you're probably already aware, but flushing iptables doesn't change or delete the default policy for a chain, only its rules.  If running `iptables -S` shows a line `-P INPUT DROP` and you don't have any rules explicitly allowing the connection then it will be dropped by default.

Comment: Hi. There were drop rules I hadn't added any. When I upgraded it was at default.

Answer (score 0):

Solved;

Not sure if it was all or some of the following;

I set selinux to minimal;

I added your ACCEPT rule  and then I added this line to iptables

```
iptables -t raw -I PREROUTING 1 -p udp --dport 2368 -j NOTRACK
```

and I uninstalled netfilter_conntrack.

It seems libnfnet_conntrack the kmod nf_conntrack was part of the problem because that the was the last change.